# Is there a way to run output php actions to variable in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Good evening internet peoples ;)

1. I have a series of Javascript commands, which will set variables using different methods.
2. From an XML file I have output the contents of a URL and Site name to an overflow table.
3. This creates hyperlinks with tooltips etc. outputting to a frame in center of the page.

I am stuck on the following:

```
var ipaddress = [OBTAIN IPADDRESS OF SITE FROM XML FILE???];
```

From the XML file, I want to run a PHP section of code to obtain the IPAddress of the site, output the result to a table cell and then move onto the next record within the XML file.

This is the PHP I would like to employ to obtain the various sites IPAddress (Which works beautifully):

```
    <?php
    $ipInfo = dns_get_record('google.co.uk', DNS_A);
    $ip = $ipInfo[0]['ip'];
    print_r($ip);
    ?>
```

So the main question is this....How can I run the above PHP coding after reading XML file and set the IPAddress variable? Do I make sense :S

Comment: AJAX is your option. You can't run it directly, you will make a request to another page to get that value, othewise you can just echo with php something like `<?php echo "var ipaddress='".$ipaddress."';"; ?>`

Comment: You're looking for AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML). It allows you to send requests to and receive data from the server asynchronously i.e. without reloading the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Careful with W3schools, some of their documentation is bogus. http://www.w3fools.com/ Try Mozilla Developer Network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: Oh! I've got everything aligned and working great. I don't know the first thing about Ajax either. Another option would be to attempt to look at locating an IP address, from within Javascript, can this be done instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple.  In PHP, just do:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo 'var ipaddress=', json_encode($ip), ';'
```

Always JSON-encode arbitrary data you want to pass to JavaScript, so that escaping happens for you automatically.

Now, you have to load this script somehow.  One simple way is to drop this in your HTML:

```
<script src="yourScript.php"></script>
```

To be clear, you aren't running your PHP from JavaScript.  You're using PHP to dynamically create JavaScript.

Comment: But within the script example, I show that it uses a non-variable google.co.uk URL. However, I want it to pick up the URL from an XML file. So there will be a combo of:

1) Reading the first entry that has the tag of URL.
2) Run it against the PHP script.
3) Output the result to a variable.
4) Reading the second entry... and so on.

I have 83 sites, that I want to read. So that it reads the first and outputs to variable, then writes to table cell, then 2nd and 3rd and 4th etc.

Comment: What's your point?  If you have an array of data, just output the array of data.  `echo 'var yourData = ', json_encode($someArrayHere), ';';`

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate Fire-Dragon-DoL's comment in a way that may help you get started.

```
<head>
... other stuff

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    $ipInfo = dns_get_record('google.co.uk', DNS_A);
    $ip = $ipInfo[0]['ip'];
    echo 'var ipAddress = "' . $ip . '";';
?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
.... all your existing stuff
```

So you are basically creating javascript from within the PHP code running on the server, but as its placed in the document it runs just like you had written it manually into the head of the html document.

The variable ipAddress will be available to all your other javascript's as it will be placed globally. So you can just use it in any other javascritp that loads after this new section.

Comment: Ya know...I think something has just clicked in my brain! lol

I've added your script to a test page then added: <script>document.write(ipAddress);</script> within the html body, and ys know what.........it works. Ok, next is for me to attempt to find a way of reading the xml. One question however, I notice that your script above does not show a function. As if I was to treat the php as a function within a javascript, and call when needed, would it work I wonder....hmmm will try.